# How to get the current page's Title property via inline code?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I set my page titles like so:

```
<%@ Page Title="Sub Page Title" %>
```

In my Master Page's Page_Load event, I modify the title to prefix them with the site name, like so:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Page.Title = "My Website Name - " + MyMainContentPlaceholder.Page.Title
End Sub
```

Now.. in each of my content pages, I have a header, that I want to match the page title.  But when I try to set the text with inline code, it grabs the final concatenated master page title.

```
<%@ Page Title="Sub Page Title" ...blah blah... %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MyMainContentPlaceholder" runat="server">
    <div class="pageHeader"><%=Me.Page.Title%></div>
</asp:Content>
```

`<%=Me.Page.Title%>` returns "My Website Name - Sub Page Title" instead of just "Sub Page Title".

How can I get it to ONLY pull the current sub page's title property?

Comment: You have defined the page title on page load including "My Website Name", that's why its returning like this

Comment: can't you just take everything to the right of the hyphen? `Me.Page.Title.Split('-')[1].Trim()`  ps. this will work a lot better if none of your page titles already have hyphens

Comment: This has nothing to do with C#, removing the tag... Next time please tag your question properly.

Answer (score 0):

If

> "My Website Name -"

is a fixed string, then you can do like this:

```
Me.Page.Title.Substring("My Website Name -")
```

or you can create a static formater method and do like this:

```
<% Namespace.Classname.FormatMyPageName(Me.Page.Title) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to create a class constant in your code behind

```
Private Const PAGE_SUB_TITLE As String = "Sub Page Title"

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Page.Title = "My Website Name - " & PAGE_SUB_TITLE;
End Sub
```

Then in when you're setting the `Page.Title` to include your application name in the title, you will still have your constant for access. This will prevent the need for extra methods or string parsing. If you'd prefer not to use a constant because you like using the Html side Title property instead, you can always just make it a variable and use it slightly differently:

```
Private _pageSubTitle As String

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    _pageSubTitle = Page.Title
    Page.Title = "My Website Name - " & PAGE_SUB_TITLE;
End Sub
```